# High memory usage in Ionic app

Tags: android, angular, memory, ionic-framework

recently I have observed thath my android app uses too much of RAM.
When i open it it takes ~~120mb and after few changes of pages it goes to 400mb.
What can I do?

To change page I use popover with:

```
        this.navCtrl.setRoot(StatisticsPage);
```

Some data from profiler:
[link to data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPm88.png)

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you need to go into the child component then instead of using `this.navCtrl.setRoot(StatisticsPage);` you can use `this.navCtrl.push(StatisticsPage);`

this could be one point of improvement.

Comment: Yes I know, but I need to change pages like tabs.

Comment: Are you completely sure that due to setRoot only your app reaches at 400mb?

Comment: Of course no, I am just guessing. In chrome profiler usage seems to be lower. But when I close app in android and clear memory it shows that app had ~~400mb.

Comment: Should i delete some data from old page after setting root to new one?